# differentiation boundary of integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I got the following problem

$\int_{\ |x|\le t +1}f(x,t)dx=E(t)$

That might sound like a stupid question, but how would I got about finding $E'(t)$ ?

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Let $E(t)$ be given by

$$E(t)=\int_{-(t+1)}^{t+1}f(x,t)\,dx$$

Then, assuming the both $f(x,t)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}$ are continuous, the derivative, $E'(t)$, of $E(t)$ is given by [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$E'(t)=f(t+1,t)+f(-(t+1),t)+\int_{-(t+1)}^{t+1}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\,dx$$

Comment: Hi.  Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer?  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it.  Looking forward to your reply.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course.  ;-)